# How can I declare a local 'matrix' inside a subroutine in FORTRAN?

Tags: fortran

I am writing a subroutine to inverse a matrix.
Input is Matrix A (n by n), output is matrix invA. Inside the subroutine, I want to declare a temporary matrix "temp" dimension (n by 2n), but the declaration caused weird problem. After this line (that I emphasize below) , I also declare integer numbers i and j and initialise them i = 0,j = 0. 
But debug these values of i and j, it shows i = 1572472 ! WEIRD!!!!! if I remove the line of code " real, dimension (m, m * 2) :: temp " then everything is fine. Can anybody explain for me why ?

thanks in advance. (I am a good programmer in .Net and now learning Fortran - but it drives me crazy!)

```
program weird

implicit none

Real, Dimension (2,2)::B
Real, Dimension (2,2) ::B_inversed


B(1,1) = 0.6
B(1,2) = 0.8  
B(2,1) = -0.8
B(2,2) = 0.6

Call InverseMatrix(B,B_inversed)

contains

subroutine InverseMatrix(A, invA)
implicit none
real, intent(in), dimension (:,:) :: A  
real, intent(out), dimension (size(a,1),size(a,2)) :: invA 

real, dimension (size(a,1),2*size(a,2)) :: temp  <------THIS LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS


integer:: i,j
i = 0 !<------- 
j = 0 !<-------DEBUG line stops here, showing i = 3734648 !VERY WEIRD!!!!!

invA(1,1) =0.0
invA(1,2) =0.0
invA(2,1) =0.0
invA(2,2) =0.0

end subroutine

end program
```

This is a very straight forward FORTRAN code, but why I didn't get the right value of 'i' ?

Comment: How large is m? What compiler options you use? It could be caused by a stack overflow.

Comment: Hi Vladimir,   I tested with only 4 by 4 matrix and the problem already occurred. I am using Intel Fortran compiler

Comment: In your subroutine, `i` and `j` aren't ever actually used for anything.  Are you sure the compiler isn't optimizing them out -- leaving only uninitialized symbols for the sake of the debugger (since you compiled with `-g`)?

Comment: @mgilson : I was using them in later statements..but as I found out they were not assigned correctly, and after I eliminated other causes of the problems, I found out the line that caused problem as I showed above....So no, it was not that the compiler optimizing those variables.

Comment: What happens if you output the values of i and j with a write statement instead of using the debugger?   I did this with gfortran on a Mac and the program ran fine.

Comment: @M.S.B. AH HA ! print *, i gives the result i printed out to screen = 0, while debugger showing i = 2882496. I am using Intel Fortran  with Visual Studio 2010. Thanks  M.S.B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Fortran arrays carry information about their own sizes a better approach would be for you to start your subroutine a bit more like this:

```
subroutine inversematrix(a, inva)
    ! ALWAYS include the next line within any scoping unit
    implicit none
    real, intent(in), dimension (:,:) :: a  ! no need to tell the compilers what the dims are
    real, intent(out), dimension (size(a,1),size(a,2)) :: inva 

    real, dimension (size(a,1),2*size(a,2)) :: temp
```

To answer your question, I can't immediately see why your code doesn't work and why the variable `i` doesn't keep the value you assign to it.  I wonder whether it is connected to the interface of the subroutine.  In modern Fortran it's always a good idea to ensure, when technically feasible, that the compiler generates the necessary routine interface.  One way to achieve this is to put all your routines into modules and *use-associate* them, another is to write your code with the basic structure

```
program
! declarations
! executable statements
contains

subroutine ...
end subroutine

end program
```

rather than

```
subroutine ...
end subroutine

program
! declarations
! executable statements
end program
```

but I'm really just guessing.

Use `implicit none` and ensure that the compiler generates routine interfaces; these may not cure your immediate problem but they're good general guidelines and will save you a lot of pain in future.

Comment: @Mark: Thank you for the new approach, it is much better than mine. However the last line was still the problem. If I then declare     integer::i,j and assign i = 0, debugger found i is not 0 but a random number 1767672!!!. I just can't understand what was wrong here!

Comment: Enable run-time error checking, you can have some index overflow, or a similar problem. You may try `-g -check all -traceback -warn all -fstack-protector -debug`

Comment: @Mark: Your guideline are very useful for programming - thank you for that. Below is my whole program. Very Straight forward - I just can't understand why. But after the line i = 0. It appears that i =3734648. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The Intel compiler does some things during optimization that may affect your debugger's output:

1. It rearranges the order of statements, so the line that assigns j = 0 may run before the line that assigns i = 0.
2. It "optimizes out" variables, not only by removing unused variables, but by combining variables with other variables that are not being used at the same time.

Both of these can seem unpredictable (at least to me). So if you've fixed your program so that it has the correct behavior, and printing the value yields the right answer, the debugger might still show the wrong value. You can try turning the optimization down/off and see what happens.